# Limits of sequences from given conditions and relations between the general terms $a_n, b_n, c_n$.

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits

> Let $a_n, b_n, c_n$ be sequences such that 
>   $$a_n+b_n+c_n=2n+1,$$ 
>   $$a_nb_n +b_nc_n +a_nc_n=2n-1,$$ 
>   $${a_n}{b_n}{c_n} =-1.$$ 
>   It is also given that $a_n \gt b_n \gt c_n $.
>
> Then what is the value of the following?
>
> a) $\lim_{{n}\rightarrow {\infty}}\frac{a_n}{n} $.
>
> b) $\lim_{n\rightarrow{-\infty}}\frac{a_n}{n}$.

I took $b_n+c_n=2n+1-a_n$ and $b_nc_n=\frac{-1}{a_n}$.

Now the second condition which can be written as $(c_n+b_n)a_n + b_nc_n=2n-1$
now changes to $(2n+1-a_n)a_n - \frac{1}{a_n}=2n-1$.

I have absolutely no idea on what to do next. I tried reducing $a_n$ into something in terms of $n$, but I have gotten nowhere. How can this question be solved?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$a_n$, $b_n$ and $c_n$ are the roots of
$$x^3-(2n+1)x^2+(2n-1)x+1=0.$$
This factors as
$$(x-1)(x^2-2nx-1)=0.$$
The roots are $b_n=1$, $a_n=n+\sqrt{n^2+1}$ and $c_n=n-\sqrt{n^2+1}$.
The limits should be straightforward now.